# Problem while loading a Vue app on local machine, not getting the result as desired

Tags: vue.js

Desired result

[image]

Result I'm getting

[image]

Header.vue code

```
<template>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
     <router-link to="/" class="navbar-brand">Stock Trader</router-link>
     </div>
    
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <router-link to="/portfolio" activeClass="active" tag="li"><a>Portfolio</a></router-link>
           <router-link to="/stocks" activeClass="active" tag="li"><a>Stocks</a></router-link>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li><a href="#">End day</a> </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
                  <a
                       href="#"
                       class="dropdown-toggle"
                       data-toggle="dropdown"
                       role="button"
                       aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">Save & Load <span class="caret"></span></a> 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a  href="#">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Load Data</a></li>
           
              </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</nav>
</template>


Advise me if anything else is required.

index.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stock Trader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
<!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7UUj.jpg)

Please advise: Problem while loading a Vue app on local machine, not getting the result as desired. I'm getting a warning however there is no CORS error once checking by pressing f12.

I've attached the third screenshot that shows warning

Comment: Your CSS styles aren't importing - are you trying to use Bootstrap? Or a different framework? It could also help to provide us a link where you got your code from since it sounds like you're pulling it from somewhere :)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Bootstrap and I mentioned it on the index.html

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
I'm taking a course and following the code.

Comment: If you press F12 do you see a CORS error in the console?

Comment: Can you also post your index.html file

Comment: No error as such, but getting a warning. yes sure will be editing my post and will post the warning as well as my index file as comments will not allow.

Comment: Issue not yet solved.

Comment: Please check my new post for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/">Stock Trader</router-link>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <router-link class="nav-link" to="/portfolio"
              >Portfolio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></router-link
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="nav-link" to="/stocks">Stocks</router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
```

Make sure that bootstrap is properly installed.

npm install --save bootstrap // install bootstrap
import in main.js file of vue by using the below import
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: Worked only for sometime however when I tried to add more for bootstrap styles. Not getting the desired result.